# how to check for localStorage value, before page loads

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a function named `validateLogin` in `index.html` where I set the local-Storage value key `userID`, and on return `true` of this function, I load other web-page (home.html) where I used this local-Storage value `userID`, but now, I need to restrict user and redirect them to signup.html, if local-Storage is empty when `home.html` is accessed directly without the `validateLogin` function or localStorage is empty ,
I tried below but its not working, what am I doing wrong?

**index.html**

```
<form id="login_form" name="login" action="home.html" method=POST onsubmit="return validateLogin()">
<script>
  var userid;
  function validateLogin() {
    userid = document.getElementById('user_id').value;
    localStorage.setItem("userID",userid);
    var passid = document.getElementById('pass_id').value;
    if ((userid.length < 3) || (passid.length < 6)) {
      document.getElementById('user_error').setAttribute("style", "color:red")
      document.getElementById('user_error').innerHTML = "invalid username/password.";
      return false;
    }
    preventBack();
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

**home.html**

```
<body>
  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <div id="nav-placeholder">
  </div>
  <!--end of Navigation bar-->

<script>
  window.onload = checkUser;
  function checkUser(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("userID") === "") {
      window.location ="signup.html";
    } 
    else {
      $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav_auth.html");
    }
  };
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: remove `window.onload = checkUser;

           function checkUser(){`  and the last `};`

Comment: Tried, but its still not working

Comment: so do you want to check if the localStorage data is present or not as soon as home.html is loaded? or do you want to check it when the loading is done?

Comment: `if (localStorage.getItem("userID")) ("#nav-placeholder").load("nav_auth.html"); else  window.location.replace("signup.html");`

Comment: thanks @mplungjan ..its working now, but not sure why else part was not working

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.getItem` returns null if the key doesn't exist, while you are doing a strict equality check on the empty string.

Replace

```
if (localStorage.getItem("userID") === "")
```

with

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("userID"))
```

Comment: I recreated your home.html and changed `if (localStorage.getItem("userID") === "")` to `if (!localStorage.getItem("userID"))`. It is redirecting to signup.html as expected. Make sure that you don't already have userID in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

If the script tag is in bottom of page no need for window.onload = checkUser; so remove it. 
Put a loader in the start of the function check if userID exists navigate to home page if it doesn't keep the user on the login/signup.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it by that.

```
if ("userId" in localStorage) {
                alert('yes');
                
            } else {
                alert('no');
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
localStorage.getItem("toto")
```

returns null if the key is not found, so you should check for null instead of empty string

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("userID")){

}
```

Worked for me